# Injecting other service's parameters in my own service

Tags: symfony

I would like to know if it is possible to inject service's parameters in my own service and if yes, how?

Let me put you in context. I'm using the `FOSFacebookBundle` which loads some configuration from the `config.yml` file. Those configuration settings (like my facebook `app_id`, `secret`, `cookie`, etc.) are kept has parameters by the `FOSFacebookBundle` with this code:

```
// FOS\FacebookBundle\DependencyInjection\FOSFacebookExtension.php
foreach (array('file', 'app_id', 'secret', 'cookie', 'domain', 'logging', 'culture', 'permissions') as $attribute) {
    $containerBuilder->setParameter('fos_facebook.'.$attribute, $config[$attribute]);
}
```

I know it is possible to retrieve those parameters via the `$container` by doing:

```
$container->getParameter('fos_facebook.app_id');
```

But I would like to know if it is possible to inject those parameters directly into one of my service definition. I have one service called `FacebookHelper` which would need this information. So I would like to do something like:

```
acme.helper.facebook:
  class: Application\AcmeBundle\Helper\FacebookHelper
  arguments:
    entityManager: "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
    facebook: "@fos_facebook.api"
    facebookAttributes:
      - "@fos_facebook.app_id"
      - "@fos_facebook.secret"
      - "@fos_facebook.cookie"
```

Of course, this syntax doesn't work because Symfony is looking for a service named `fos_facebook.app_id` which doesn't exist.

I'm looking for a solution that would avoid to inject the container directly in my service. Either by doing a direct definition in my `services.yml` file, or via the DI extension of my bundle which would do some work to define my custom service, retrieve the parameters from `FOSFacebookBundle` and inject them in it.

Regards,
Matt

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In fact, it is really easy and I feel ashamed that I didn't think about it before posting my question. I knew about how to use parameters in the `config.yml` file (i.e. by using %locale% for example) but I didn't think about using this syntax to inject parameters in my service definition.

Here is how I injected `FOSFacebookBundle` parameters in my service:

```
acme.helper.facebook:
  class: Application\AcmeBundle\Helper\FacebookHelper
  arguments:
    entityManager: "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
    facebook: "@fos_facebook.api"
    facebookAttributes:
      appId: "%fos_facebook.app_id%"
      secret: "%fos_facebook.secret%"
      permissions: "%fos_facebook.permissions%"
```

So simple :)
Hope this will help someone else.

Regards,
Matt